# Could not find file 'obj\Debug\OldProjectName.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to publish project (tools vs2010), but cannot all the time getting the error below.
I paste to my projects files from another project and then I changed namespace (OldProjectName) to the parent project (NewProjectName). But it still getting information from somewhere about old project.

I cleaned solution, builded, rebuilded. Closed and reopened again and all the time the same error.

I'm able to build project but publish it.

Any ideas what can cause the problem?

> Error 1   Copying file
>   obj\Debug\OldProjectName.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt to
>   obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\OldProjectName.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
>   failed. Could not find file
>   'obj\Debug\OldProjectName.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt'.       0   0   NewProjectName

Answer (score 34):

1. Open your .csproj file in notepad
2. Find "obj\Debug\OldProjectName.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt"
3. Remove that line and save it
4. Open your project and try to publish it and this time you will be succeeded.

Note: if you are getting any more file like .pdb remove that as well. 
**Hope it will help you**

Comment: Editing the csproj resolved the issue. Somehow the project held onto the reference, but didn't show it in the IDE.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the obj folder is not read only, if so change read only property of this folder to false. this worked for me.

Comment: This was my case because my co-programmer had checked in items that did not belong in source control. (So I marked for delete and submitted the changelist.)

Comment: I had also to reload the project after unchecked the read-only attribute. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check the permissions to the folder obj\Debug\ if you give it write permissions, the error would go away.

Comment: I'm running VS as administrator. and I checked permissions looks fine. I don't see this file at all under debug folder, so I think it's reading it from temp files probably...

Comment: This turned out to because someone (ahem, me) ran a build directly on the build server in that folder, while logged in as a user different than the TFS service account.

Answer (score 3):

Check if the folders "bin" and "obj" are checked-in to source control, if so delete those two folders in source control. There is no need to check-in these two folders to source folders. Also make sure that these folders "obj" and "bin" are deleted from your hard disk, they will be created again after a build.

Hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is your responsibility to make copies so you can go **back to one.**

Open your project file (vb/cs)proj with a notepad, and search for the missing files.

In my case I got this error when I tried to publish the project and certain files were not found.

Each publish attempt I got another file name, after checking that the file actually didn't exist in the project, I removed it from the project file, manually.

Then publish succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the obj folder and build again.

Ref: http://forums.asp.net/t/1402005.aspx

Comment: It's not enough alone.

Answer (score 2):

Like many others these files were read only and needed to be deleted or actually able to be overwritten by VS. However, as may be the case for many others, the problem was because these files were checked in to source control. Your bin and obj folders should not be in source control. Mark them for delete and submit the changelist.

One exception to the rule is for the bin folder could be dll files that are not .Net compatible. Such as a C/C++ dll that you are using through a .Net wrapper dll. I mark them as content so that they get published and check them into source control.

Answer (score 1):

I too had this problem. I resolved this by deleting files inside project bin folder (.dll and .pdb) and closed and re-opened VS .

Answer (score 1):

The file named **FileListAbsolute.txt** was deleted from the folder obj/debug. Visual Studio can automatically recreate the file and others in the obj/debug for you.
For VS to recreate it, set the configuration of the solution and the project to **debug mode**. Then rebuild your solution.

To change the configuration mode to debug, from the solution explorer, right-click on the solution name and select **Properties**.

Select **Configuration** under **Configuration Properties**. Then select **Debug** from the dropdown list.
Click **Apply** and **OK**. Ensure that in Configuration Manager, the configuration mode is also a debug mode.

Then rebuild your solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me using solution here: [Certain Razor views not publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308017/certain-razor-views-not-publishing)

Excluding the views folder and re-including fixed it for me. So it's possible for anyone else experiencing this it may be as simple as excluding and then including the file/folder in question of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this bug using VS2017 with a solution stored in OneDrive.I suspected OneDrive's sync mechanism to be the root cause of this.
When I tried to reproduce using VS2019 however it did not reappear. Looks solved in between these versions.