# Certain Razor views not publishing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, publish

Using VS 2017 with MVC 5 Razor views.  When I publish my application, a handful of specific views do not get copied over.

I'd discovered several SE questions on this same issue from back in the 2010-2011 timeframe.  At the time, the issue was that Build Action in the file's properties was not set to Content due to a bug in some early RC which has since been resolved.  Well, all of mine already *do* day Content for Build Action.

Any reason why only a small number of views are not making it in the publish?

Comment: How are you publishing your site?

Comment: @DavidG File System via VS publish feature

Comment: Are the views included in the project flie?

Comment: If you select the view, then in the Properties view the Build Action, what does it say?  It should say Content; sometimes that can get switched.

Comment: @DavidG yeah my bad.... I jumped too early :-)  that is the only reason I know of why

Comment: @DavidG Good call on checking if they're included.  What a strange issue, though, because they *were* included, but the project file had the include as `None Include` rather than `Content Include`.  So I exluded the view folders and re-included them and the issue is now resolved.  I bet it had something to do with the fact that I autogenerated the views with a utility I wrote and clicked/dragged them into the solution from Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there are only 2 things that can cause this to happen.

1. As you say in the question, the build action for each view needs to be set to "Content"
2. The view files need to be included in the project file, so in the `.csproj` file there should be a line like this:

   ```
   <Content Include="Views\ControllerName\Index.cshtml" />
   ```

Comment: Everyone should read my comment under my OP for how I think this happened.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin - yup!  You are 100% on how this happened.  If you add a file *outside* of visual studio to your solution folder (drag/drop via windows explorer for instance), VS will **not** publish that file as it is not part of the solution.  You will have to go into VS solution explorer and click the "Show All Files" option.  Navigate to where your file should be.  If the file is greyed out, right click, choose "Include in project".

Comment: @Tommy I don't think it should work that way, though.  When dragging a .cshtml file into the project, it *is* included, meaning you don't have to right-click the greyed-out icon and select *Include in Project*.  What happens is that it's added to the project with an XML tag that prevents it from publishing.  The fix was to exclude it then re-include it which is a hack to trick VS into thinking it was added through the project directly.  I click/drag .cs files into the solution all the time and they compile with the rest of the assembly, but VS treats Razor views slightly differently.

Comment: No need to worry about it now, the new .Net Core csproj format doesn't include the files so they'll always be included by the build process.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin - correct.  If you drag it *into* or *around* the VS solution explorer, it should be good to go as you said, VS will know all about the file and include it.  I was referencing dragging a file into Windows Explorer where your solution is.  At that point, VS will not have any idea that it should be part of the solution (prior to .Net core at least).

Answer (score 4):

Another one would be to set this in your csproje file. This was missing in mine, which caused it to make a `precompiledviews.dll` in my publish:

`<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>`

Set it to `false` explicitely in order to publish .cshtml files.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I added the tag under a propertygroup tag and I could see the .cshtml files in the build output.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio -> Right click on "Views" in solution explorer. Click "Publish Views". This will set all the views to Content"

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of Visual Studio, excluding and then including partial view or its folder may work or not. The most certain way to do it is to remove it from `.csproj` file and then include it again.

lets say `_LoginPartial` is not updated after publishing (especially if you have some razor code).

First open '.csproj' file, and remove

```
<Content Include="Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml" />
```

The build the project, and then add it again to `.csproj`, and rebuild and publish.

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution From Visual Studio

1. right-click on the file and "**Exclude From Project**".
2. select the Project and click on "**Show All Files**" from Solution Explore (top horizontal menu bar on Solution Explore)
3. right-click on the file that Excluded and Click on "**Include In Project**".

This will automatically modify the .csproj file.