# Specific View not updating content after publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, razor, publish, asp.net-mvc-views

This is the new little code on my View.cshtml:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(i => i.vVendaUnitarioSemImpostoSemFormatacao)
```

When I'm on **debug mode, it works normally**, but when I put in **release mode** and publish on azure, doesn't update what I've codded.

I've already tried:

1. Click on compiling before publishing in visual studio options.
2. Tried to set true on .csproj `<MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>`
3. Publishing from another computer
4. Change another View from my project and works normally, but that one specifically don't.
5. Tried to put `optimizeCompilations="true` on `<compilation>` in web.config
6. Tried to copy and paste on ftp project to check if will work.

Someone can help me on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this post [Certain Razor views not publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45308017/certain-razor-views-not-publishing) . What I did to resolve the problem was create another view, with another name and change the code where I'm calling the old view.

Comment: In case this doesn't work: I also have this now and then. In my case I have accidentally published the specific View. It is then created on the server and called by the compiled application. It ignores all future changes to the view in general publishes (really annoying). What I do, I go to Kudu->Powershell then /site/wwwroot and depending on where that view is in your explorer navigate to that spot en delete the view.