# Visual Studio 2017 .Net Publishing WebAPI DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferences

Tags: visual-studio-2017, asp.net-web-api2, publishing

I have one WebAPI project which builds successfully but when I try to publish, it gives me the below error-

Copying file obj\Debug\DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferences.cache to obj\Release\AspnetCompileMerge\Source\obj\Debug\DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferences.cache failed. 
Could not find file 'obj\Debug\DesignTimeResolveAssemblyReferences.cache'

Things I tried-
1. Clean rebuild
2. Deleteing Obj and Bin folder manually and rebuild

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346984/could-not-find-file-obj-debug-oldprojectname-csproj-filelistabsolute-txt/8253471 take a look.

Comment: Thanks Sumit. It worked !